# Transport from Canary Islands to Casablanca?

Tags: air-travel, transportation, morocco, canary-islands, gran-canaria

I'm having trouble finding transportation from [Gran Canaria](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Canaria) of the [Canary Islands](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canary_Islands) to [Casablanca](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca) Morocco, for November. The flights I've seen take twenty-something hours because of stops in other places.

Are there any inexpensive fights between Gran Canaria and Casablanca?

Do the sibling islands have direct flights to Morocco?

Are there alternatives? Ferries to the mainland perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

A quick [Google Search](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=flights+from+gran+canaria+to+casablanca&oq=gran+canaria+to+casablancA) shows that Royal Air Maroc offer services via Tenerife (about 4 hours travelling time), and they have also listed a direct service later in October (around 2.5 hours)

Comment: Apparently no such flights in November. Is there a seasonal consideration, when flights cease in this area?